# Iphone SE sound stops during a telephone call of 2+ minutes

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I hope this is the appropriate place to ask this question. I saw more hardware related issues here, but it may also be a configuration / setting problem.

The problem is with my **iPhone SE (2020 i think) 64GB** it says on the box. **After calling for 2-5 minutes my sound input and output stop. So no one hears me talk and I cannot talk**..

What I did was check "do not disturb" setting, is is not enabled. Further I reseted the network settings, so had to retype wifi password and stuff. Also checked time limit setting but there is none. The settings are mostly default. Plus I started to have this problem after a few months after purchasing the phone without changing relevant settings to cause this.

The **iOS version is 14.6**. I updated that a few weeks ago.

Anybody have an idea to what I am doing wrong, or the phone is bugged?

Thanks in advance for a possible solution.

Comment: DND should not related to this, looks like a hardware issue to me. Try talking with a bluetooth headset/AirPods or wired iPods to try to pinpoint the issue further.